# Assigning Ranges to Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I have been struggling with this for quite some time, but the error dialogue box that pops up isn't exactly the most helpful.  I'm trying to extract a list of names from the worksheet and assigning them to an array using the range function. I tried and tried, but I couldn't seem to get it to work, so I tried reading in the cells 1 by 1 instead, using the Do Until Loop.  I didn't expect to be posting this here, so the code of what I was doing before, is already gone, but here's an example:

```
Dim RangeList As Variant
RangeList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").Range("H1:H132").Value2
```

I switched it to the next method in hopes that it would lead to a more straightforward approach:

```
ReDim ResourceList(ResourceLength - 1)
I = 1
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").Cells(I, 8).Value = ""
    ResourceList(I) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").Cells(I, 8).Value
    Workbooks("NEW PROJECT PLAN").Worksheets("Console").Cells(I, 2).Value = Resource
    I = I + 1
Loop
```

The first one returns an empty range that 'Can't find any cells' and the second one gave me an array of empty strings 169 items long.  I feel like I'm pounding my head against a brick wall on this one, any help would be appreciated.
Here is the entirety of the code that I'm trying to troubleshoot:

```
'Collects the List of Resources
Dim ResourceLength As Long, I As Integer
Dim ResourceList() As String
ResourceLength = ThisWorkbook.FinalRow(8, "Plan")
MsgBox ("Final Row is: " & ResourceLength) 'The Last row used in column 8

ReDim ResourceList(ResourceLength - 1)
I = 1
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").Cells(I, 8).Value = ""
    ResourceList(I - 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").Cells(I, 8).Value
    Workbooks("NEW PROJECT PLAN").Worksheets("Console").Cells(I, 2).Value = Resource
    I = I + 1
Loop

ResourceList = ThisWorkbook.FilterArray(ResourceList)
Dim myCount As Integer
Dim Source As Variant

For Each Source In ResourceList
    Worksheets("Console").Cells(myCount, 1).Value = Source
    myCount = myCount + 1
Next Source
```

Here is the FilterArray Function:

```
Public Function FilterArray(UnsortedArray As Variant) As Variant
Dim Intermediate() As Variant
Dim UItem As Variant
' Runs through each item and compares it to the list of items found, if it finds repeats, it throws them out.
For Each UItem In UnsortedArray
    If Not ArrayItemExist(Intermediate, UItem) Then
        ' The Item does not Exist
        ReDim Intermediate(UBound(Intermediate) + 1)
        Intermediate(UBound(Intermediate)) = UItem
    End If
Next UItem
' Returns the Sorted Array.
FilterArray = Intermediate
End Function

Private Function ArrayItemExist(TargetArray() As Variant, TargetItem As Variant) As Boolean
    'Searches an Array for TargetItem and returns a boolean stating whether it exists within the Array or not.
    Dim ItemFound As Boolean
    Dim SItem As Variant
    ItemFound = False
    For Each SItem In TargetArray
        If TargetItem = SItem Then
            ItemFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next SItem
    ArrayItemExist = ItemFound
End Function

Public Function FinalRow(Column As Integer, Sheet As String) As Long
    ' Finds the last Row used in the spreadsheet.
    FinalRow = Worksheets(Sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, Column).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

When I try to run the software, I receive an error that the For Loop is not initialized, which I traced back to the 'ResourceList' Array/Range being empty.

[Edit]
This function is used to prep an array of names that are extracted from a list of dropdown box resources. This list may contain multiple instances of the same name, so it's sent to the FilterArray function to sort the array into an array with just one instance of each name. Example:
[Before and after sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scvVC.png)

After this, it's sent to a module that will inject each name into a dictionary with a corresponding amount of hours that the person is scheduled to work.

Comment: In the first snippet of code change `Dim RangeList As Variant` into `Dim RangeList() As Variant`.

Comment: The first one works for me (are the names in column H or I?), but for the second one there are a few issues: `.Cells(I, 8)` is incorrect. It should be `.Cells(8, "I")`, and you are using a one-dimensional array, when it should be a 2d array; also `ThisWorkbook.FinalRow(8, "Plan")` is incorrect.. But I think a dictionary could be better for this

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to do with the names from `Worksheets("Plan").Columns(H) (or I), and maybe add a before and after image?

Comment: You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  [Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=28) and [Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&t=245s&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=43) are the most relevant.

Comment: Two issues I notice: 1- you `ReDim ResourceList(ResourceLength - 1)` as if you want to use it as 0-based array, but in fact uou use it as `1-based`, so better use `ReDim ResourceList(1 to ResourceLength)`  2- The first time you call `ArrayItemExist(Intermediate, UItem)`, `Intermediate` is empty, so the `For Each` loop in `ArrayItemExist` cant initialize. Quick-fix: `Dim Intermediate As Variant` and start the `ArrayItemExist` routine with `If IsEmpty(TargetArray) Then exit function`.

Comment: But it is pretty obvious that a `Dictionary` can simplify tremendously the task you're on, as in the previous comments.

Comment: A dictionary may work, I will give it a try when I get home from work, thank you, I'll also add pictures of what I'm trying to accomplish, would it help to know that all of the names I'm trying to read in from the sheet are coming from a dropdown menu? Also, I am trying to convert an array that may have multiples of a single name, into an array that has just one instance of each name